# Comparing learnt features in deep learning

Tags: clustering, deep-learning

What is the standard practice to compare learnt features for different deep learning features quantitatively. These features would be used to score similarity between the items.

E.g. I use different pre-trained image classification models from [Keras](https://keras.io/applications/) and now want to compare the features extracted before the classification layers across the different models to understand which model's features are better able to capture the similarity between the images (on which they are not trained) quantitatively, how would I do that?

Can we apply the methods (e.g. purity of clustering, etc.) that have been discussed [here](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1036) (Evaluation methods for unsupervised word embeddings)?

Comment: Compare for what purpose? To be answerable, this question would need some edits to explain more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited the question with details on the purpose of comparison.

Comment: Just use any standard feature selection approach you would use for any other features... also [searching older threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-selection%5D+images) could be useful.